# React router V4 / V5 / V6 nested routing 404 net::ERR_ABORTED 404,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, nested, react-router-dom

**I have tested everything described below with both react router V4 and V5. In V4 the error is just 404, but in V5 it also includes net::ERR_ABORTED.**

I am creating a React app with React router. I need to have a `/test` route and `/test/:param1/:param2` route.

First route is OK, but when I created the second and navigated the browser to `localhost:8080/test/something/something2` I received a blank page with error in the console saying that it failed to `GET localhost:8080/test/something/index.js`.

I am using webpack and webpack-dev-server. I then tested more:

1. Tried to put the second route inside the component of the first.
2. Tried simplifying the route to /test/:param1, but that didn't work either.
3. I then tried just a normal 1 level nested route /test/test2(no parameters) and still got the error in the title.

I have also configured a `404` page, however it is displayed only if the path is 1 level: `/{something that does't exist}`. If I navigate to `/{something}/{something more}` I get the same `ERR_ABORTED`.

For some unknown to me reason the browser tries to `GET /test/index.js`, which obviously doesn't exist.

I spent a day looking through articles, tutorials, and the react router documentation, but everywhere nested routes just work. In fact there is absolutely nothing about this error.

Edit1: After some more testing I've been able to narrow down the issue to just one  question: **How to configure react-router to always look for the bundle at {domain, localhost:port}/index.js?**

Edit2: Tested it with the beta of V6 - same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours I finaly figured it out!! The mistake was so dumb. In my `index.html` file I required the bundle with `<script src="./index.js"></script>`. Simply removing the dot fixed the issue. If somebody has the same error, first check your index.html.

Comment: OMG!! I exactly had the same mistake! Day saved :D

Answer (score 6):

Another is to check if you have in the Webpack config the following:

```
output: {publicPath: '/'},
```

Took me some time.

Comment: took me just a search in google to find your answer :)